# how to accept an interface type in functional options

Tags: go

I am trying to use functional options for my project acorrding to [uber go guide here](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#functional-options)

but now I have a option field that accept an interface:

```
type CommandParser interface {
    Parse(string)
}

type MyCommandParser struct {
}

func (c *MyCommandParser) Parse(row string) {
    // parse something
}

type appOption struct {
    appName   string
    CmdParser CommandParser
}

type AppOption interface {
    apply(*appOption)
}

// this can work
type appName string

func (h appName) apply(o *appOption) {
    o.appName = string(h)
}
func WithAppName(name string) AppOption {
    return appName(name)
}

// this can not work, because 'cmdParser' is an interface type and it cannot has a receiver
type cmdParser CommandParser // CommandParser is an interface
func (c cmdParser) apply(o *appOption) {
    o.CmdParser = CommandParser(c)
}

// WithCmdParser add command parser for app
func WithCmdParser(command CommandParser) AppOption {
    return CommandParser(command)
}

type App struct {
    // ...
}

func NewApp(opts ...AppOption) *App {
    o := &appOption{}
    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt.apply(o)
    }
    app := &App{}
    // apply option to app
    // ...
    return app
}

func main() {
    app := NewApp(WithAppName("new app"), WithCmdParser(&MyCommandParser{}))
    // maybe I need another command parser
    // app := NewApp(WithAppName("new app"), WithCmdParser(&MyCommandParser2{}))
    // ...
}
```

I know this code didn't work, because `cmdParser` is an interface, so I cannot add a receiver on `type cmdParser CommandParser`. it just something like a fake code.

the finally what I excpet behavier is: It can work when I call `NewApp()` with parameter `WithCmdParser(&MyCommandParser{})`, I want my `App` that can accept any value that implement the `CaommandParser`. But I dont know how to do that with this code style.

I can make it work with this way:

```
type cmdParser []CommandParser // CommandParser is an interface
func (c cmdParser) apply(o *appOption) {
    o.CmdParser = c[0]
}

// WithCmdParser add command parser for app
func WithCmdParser(command CommandParser) AppOption {
    return cmdParser([]CommandParser{command})
}
```

but I think it is not a good solution. there a more smart way to do that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "didn't work"?  It's hard to tell what exact problem you're having.

Comment: The method declaration `func (c cmdParser) apply(o *appOption)` is illegal because `cmdParser` is an interface type and Go does not allow interfaces to have method declarations. The `type cmdParser CommandParser` declaration doesn't make much sense, it has no utility that I'm aware of given that `CommandParser` is an interface.

Comment: *"I want to know how to do that?"* -- What you are trying to do doesn't make sense, as I've already pointed out in the previous comment. So, rather than expecting the SO community to infer what you want to do from non-sensical code, you should explain what you would like to achieve using the english language.